# Multiple images in carousel on bootstrap DW CC

Tags: carousel

I am new to bootstrap - but would really like to add multiple images to a carousel?

This is what I have so far, but it only seems to recognise three slides? so when I tried to add code for fourth slide - it didn't seem to recognise it.
How do I include multiple images please?  I have 30 in my image folder.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.  And simple instructions please as I am not all that tekky! thankyou

I have tried to copy the coding used to add images to the Carousel function in Bootstrap, using DW cc, but cannot seem to add any more than three images?

Comment: Here is the official documentation for it -- > https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

If you know the exact names of the files you can add them  by setting the src to the file location such as src="files/file.jpg"  here ->
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">

Comment: It could also be a directory rights issue , do you have IIS access?  What does your file directory structure look like?  Are all the files in the www directory directly?

Comment: please add details to your question to help identify the issue, and add the appropriate Bootstrap tag according to your version